# Mysql query multiple select statements output on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, multiple-columns, multiple-select

Table

```
+------+-------+------------------+
|CLIENT| VALUE |    DATETIME      |
+------+-------+------------------+
|  A   |  1    | 2018-11-10 09:00 |
|  B   |  1    | 2018-11-10 09:00 |
|  C   |  1    | 2018-11-10 09:00 |
|  D   |  2    | 2018-11-10 08:00 |
|  E   |  2    | 2018-11-10 08:00 |
|  F   |  3    | 2018-11-10 08:00 |
|  A   |  1    | 2018-11-10 07:00 |
|  B   |  2    | 2018-11-10 07:00 |
|  C   |  2    | 2018-11-10 07:00 |
|  D   |  3    | 2018-11-10 06:00 |
|  E   |  1    | 2018-11-10 06:00 |
|  F   |  2    | 2018-11-10 06:00 |
|  A   |  1    | 2018-11-08 08:00 |
|  B   |  2    | 2018-11-08 08:00 |
|  C   |  2    | 2018-11-08 08:00 |
|  D   |  1    | 2018-11-08 08:00 |
|  E   |  1    | 2018-11-08 07:00 |
|  F   |  2    | 2018-11-08 07:00 |
```

I'm newbie to mysql, and I'm in trouble with this query.

I have only one table named "table" with three columns.

This table records many data every day at different time from a specific set of client A,B,C,D,E,F

With one query I need to create new table with one row for each client and with the following 4 columns:

1. first column should contain the newest value recordered in the table for each client
2. second column should contain the percentage of time the value is equal to 1 for each client during the last 24 hours
3. third column should contain the percentage of time the value is equal to 1 for each client during the last 7 days
4. as previous column but during the last 30 days

I hope someone can help me.

What I would like to receive:

```
+------+-------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|CLIENT| NEWEST VALUE| LAST 24 H | LAST 7 DAYS  | LAST 30 DAYS |
+------+-------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|  A   |       1     |    100%   |      100%    |     ...      | 
|  B   |       1     |     50%   |       66%    |     ...      |
|  C   |       1     |     50%   |       33%    |     ...      |
|  D   |       2     |      0%   |       33%    |     ...      |
|  E   |       2     |     50%   |       66%    |     ...      |
|  F   |       3     |      0%   |        0%    |     ...      |
```

This piece of code works fine to create the "NEWST VALUE" column

```
SELECT
    client,
    value,
    max(datetime)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    client;
```

and this one create the "LAST 24 H" column

```
SELECT
    client,
    count(if(value = 1,1, null))/count(value),
FROM
    table
WHERE
    date(datetime) < CURRENT_DATE() - interval 1 day
GROUP BY
    repository_name;
```

but I'm not able to put all the output together in one new table

Comment: If the query is still not resolved, can you please provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ OR, `Create Table` and `Insert Into` statements would be helpful, so that we can reproduce the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Assuming pre-8.0 MySQL, only the most recent value is really tricky.  Here is one approach:

```
select t.client,
       max(case when t.datetime = c.maxdt then t.value end) as most_recent_value,
       avg(case when t.datetime >= now() - interval 1 day
                then (t.value = 1)
           end) as last_day_percentage,
       avg(case when t.datetime >= now() - interval 7 day
                then (t.value = 1)
           end) as last_7day_percentage,
       avg(case when t.datetime >= now() - interval 30 day
                then (value = 1)
           end) as last_30day_percentage                
from t join
     (select t.client, max(t.datetime) as maxdt
      from t
      group by t.client
     ) c
     on c.client = t.client
group by t.client;
```

Note that this logic uses a MySQL extension where boolean values are treated as numbers in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

The average produces "0" or "1" for the time period in question, with `NULL` values for any other record.  The `avg()` function ignores `NULL` values.